# google g+ button not working in authenticated user

Tags: google-analytics

g+(google plus) button is not working in authenticated users page, when i click the g+ button  the error image will appear instead of g+ button ,when i click the error button a popup will appear for error suggestions.

But it working in anonymous page .. any one know how let it to be work in logged in page. reply ASAP

Comment: Hello, please provide more info/errors.

Comment: are you using http and https combined? that might cause an issue when calling google.